Weighted Standard Deviation on Excel Pivot Table
I have a dataset of investments with the following columns



Investment
Investment Rating
Commitment
Region
Portfolio
Helper




A
10
100
Asia
P1
1000


B
9
250
Africa
P2
2250


C
8
300
S. America
P1
2400


D
11
125
Asia
P1
1375


E
12
150
S. America
P1
1800


F
9
200
S. America
P1
1800



I've created a pivot table that uses the Helper column and a calculated field to provide the average Investment Rating weighted by the Commitment. I'd like for the pivot table to also include the weighted standard deviation of Investment Rating. I understand how to calculate a weighted standard deviation for the entire dataset, but it's important this is in the pivot table so that I'll have the weighted standard deviation automatically calculated for data cuts and filters. I'm completely stumped by this and can't seem to find any resources online.
I've tried changing the summary value field of the weighted average field, but this doesn't work as the weighted average field is a Sum. Do I need to create a new calculated field with a different formula? Any help would be appreciated!
Edit: An example output would provide the std deviation of Investment Rating weighted by the Investment. For instance, the std deviation of Investment Ratings for each region displayed as a time series. As this would be a field in the pivot table, it would automatically update based on changes to the data filter and data cuts.

Please provide an example of the expected output

I added an edit with my expected output. I’d like for the std deviation of the weighted ratings to be a field in the pivot table so that the figure will dynamically change based on cuts and filters in the pivot table.
